# Java JMX get the logged in user

Tags: java, spring, security, jmx

I have a JMX server started by JVM process that can be optionally secured (for now its not, so I'm ready to consider any extensible way for it). For example as an option I looked at [official tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/management/agent.html) and its ok for now to use user/password authentication.
The MBeans are deployed via spring (annotations approach is used).

Now I would like to get **from within** my MBean the user name for some additional actions. Is it possible to do in JMX technology at all? If Yes how? :)

Example:

```
public class MyMBean {

    public void myOp() {

        String userName = ... ?;  // or whatever object that can bring me the name

        makeSomethingWithUserName ( userName );

        doMyStuffHere();
    }
}
```

I've found [this tutorial](http://www.java.net/node/680707) but it seems to be glassfish specific and I'm looking for plain java based solution.

Thanks a lot and have a nice day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, but the Subject is only filled if the user authenticated. A local JMX connection will give an empty Subject!

```
private String getUserName() {
    AccessControlContext acc = AccessController.getContext();
    Subject subject = Subject.getSubject(acc);
    if (subject != null)  {
    Set<JMXPrincipal> principals = subject.getPrincipals(JMXPrincipal.class);
    JMXPrincipal principal = principals.iterator().next();
    return principal.getName();
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this approach works great. Accepting your answer.