# Get details of the user that invoked the JMX operation

Tags: java, authentication, jmx

I am trying to get the details of the user that invoked the JMX operation for logging purpose. I have tried below code. But that does not seem to work as it returns blank each time. What am I dooing wrong. Or is there any better way of doing this?

```
private String getUserName() {
    AccessControlContext acc = AccessController.getContext();
    Subject subject = Subject.getSubject(acc);
    if (subject != null)  {
        Set<JMXPrincipal> principals = subject.getPrincipals(JMXPrincipal.class);
        JMXPrincipal principal = principals.iterator().next();
        return principal.getName();
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java JMX get the logged in user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12929335/java-jmx-get-the-logged-in-user)

Comment: I had checked this solution. But as I have already mentioned, it does not seem to work. That is why I am asking a new question here.

Comment: Your code differs from the answer, like the `getPrincipals` method invocation. Try updating yours to match.

Comment: I did. It still doesn't work for me. Tried that code first and then the above.

Comment: Edited the snippet to show the one in the link you shared.

Comment: Got to know that the above code works only if authentication is performed. My point here is, I want to know the user ID of the user that invoked the JMX operation. Authentication requires credentials. I am looking for user details too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above code did work.
What I did (for all that might be wondering like I was):

1) Added following JVM args

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=**false**
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=**true**
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=**PATH-TO jmxremote.access**
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=**PATH-TO jmxremote.password**
```

2) Added following entries in the jmxremote.access file

```
admin   readwrite \ create javax.management.monitor.*,javax.management.timer.* \               unregister
user   readonly
```

3) Added below lines in the jmxremote.password file

```
admin  adminPassword
user  userPassword
```

4) Added the below code in my MBean java file and called the method getUserName() inside the JMXoperation

```
private String getUserName() {
    AccessControlContext acc = AccessController.getContext();
    Subject subject = Subject.getSubject(acc);
    if (subject != null)  {
        Set<JMXPrincipal> principals = subject.getPrincipals(JMXPrincipal.class);
        JMXPrincipal principal = principals.iterator().next();
        return principal.getName();
    }
    return "";
}
```

When I run it in debug mode, I am seeing the user that invoked the JMXOperation.